# When making a piece of hardware how do I apply a license to it?

Tags: hardware

When building a digital open sourced project it is very easy to apply the licence. You can do this by putting it anywhere in the product in places such as:

- The bottom of a blog post
- In the code itself
- In the documentation

**My question:**

How do I apply a licence to a piece of hardware? Do I physically write the license to the bottom of the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go over the ways you can create files to make an open source hardware design spread:

- AutoCAD files (and other files usable for 3D printing and related manufacturing, e.g. CNC machines)
- Blueprints
- Data sheets
- Materials lists
- Assembly guides

You should apply the license to the AutoCAD files and blueprints.

You don't spread open source hardware by making physical objects available. You spread it by making the *design* available. Apply the license to the documents/files behind the design.

However, you *can*, if you want, add the license to the physical object (and sometimes it is required for some objects; see below).

Here's a specific case. From a page about [the TAPR Open Hardware License](http://www.tapr.org/ohl.html):

> If you create a design that you want to license under the OHL, you should:
>
> - Include the OHL document in a file named LICENSE.TXT (or LICENSE.PDF) that is included in the documentation package.
> - If the file format allows, include a notice like "Licensed under the TAPR Open Hardware License (www.tapr.org/OHL)" in each documentation file. **While not required, you should also include this notice on printed circuit board artwork and the product itself;** if space is limited the notice can be shortened or abbreviated.
> - Include a copyright notice in each file **and on printed circuit board artwork.**